# How to specify a URL param API token, when using ClientBase?

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to learn how to use WCF. I am writing a client library using `System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel>`. I am not sure if this is WCF or not, but it's what I found when searching the web for WCF client examples.

Anyway, I'm trying to write a client for an HTTP-based API that requires a URL param provided access token. I can't figure out how to provide this though.

Is there a way I can access the request headers directory, or maybe a more idiomatic way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the appropriate way to use WCF client for consuming HTTP-based APIs. WCF transport is a bit more complicated and has a different structure (it normally wraps everything is a message envelope, etc).

If you really want to feel all the pain and to do it using WCF, then you will need to declare a .NET interface for your HTTP Api and all the message contracts.

See the example here: http://tech.pro/tutorial/981/creating-a-rest-client-using-wcf

But, again, I would advice against doing this in the real life :)

Comment: I don't want to feel the pain. :) But, could you give me an example of some issues I'd run into? The guy in that tutorial sounds like he uses WCF to consume HTTP-based APIs pretty frequently. You can also specify that a payload is not wrapped in anything. I believe you, but I just wanted some elaboration on why it's going to be painful. Also, that URL example doesn't explain how to include an access token in the URL params, so I'm still stuck searching. :/

Comment: Well, because you will have to define all these interfaces, contract classes, translations, etc yet still providing WCF with the URL templates. Plus configuring WCF and dealing with its infrastructure... For what? Most of the time it is much simpler to just use HttpWebRequest + Json/dynamic and you are done.